# Add units to scale bar in spplot()

Tags: r, gis, lattice

I am working with R version 2.14.1-1 on Ubuntu 12.04, using spplot to plot GIS data, specifically 2008 vote tallies by precinct.

I am a bit new to R. I have researched my problem without finding a solution. I would like to add units to the scale bar, in this case something like "% of vote" running vertically down the bar.

My code so far is:

```
library(gpclib)
gpclibPermit()
library(maptools)
library(maps)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sp)
require(graphics)
library(rgdal)
library(lattice)

pennStateMap <- readShapeSpatial("/home/jgoodson/stateData/Pennsylvania/shapeFiles/pa_final.shp")
plotvar <- pennStateMap@data$USPP2008

nclr <- 10
class <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="equal")
poliPallet <- colorRampPalette(c("red1", "blue1"), space="Lab")

pennCounties <- unionSpatialPolygons(pennStateMap, as.numeric(pennStateMap@data$COUNTYFP10))

spCounties <- list("sp.polygons", as(pennCounties, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"), col.regions="transparent")

spplot(pennStateMap, "USPP2008", main="2008 Presidential Election Results by Precinct in Pennsylvania", col.regions=poliPallet(10), col="transparent", at=round(class$brks, digits=1), sp.layout = list(spCounties))
```

I tried adding the units via:
`barLabel <- list("sp.text", c(40, -71), "Dem % of Two-Party Vote",  srt=-90)`
and then adding that to `sp.layout`. But this will not go outside the drawing box for the geographic data, so it disappears when I try to get to the correct side of the scale bar.

I would appreciate any help I can get on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Since the file `pa_final.shp` is available on your computer only, the code is not reproducible.